# hylafax vs hylafax+: Compatibility issues and Asterisk interoperability

Tags: asterisk, fax

I'm an engineering student currently working on a project for making a Fax2Email and Email2Fax solution based on HylaFax and Asterisk and I'm highly concerned about performance and stability since the solution should be deployed in a production environment.
I know that the philosophy behind Hylafax+ is offering a more-advanced and stable fax server than hylafax.org's, but I'm worried about some compatibility issues, especially the possibility to import clients, connectors and related softwares from HylaFax.org to HylaFax+.
Besides, I'm planning to install Asterisk and Hylafax on the same machine as an "all-in-one" solution for easy deployment and management, is this a good idea? If so, how to get the most of it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've not had any experience with Asterisk, but we have been using HylaFax to send out fax's for years, and dont remember it ever going wrong, its always seemed a very robust product. We just have a couple of perl script on the box picking up the job control files and artwork and giving them to the HylaFax engine to send out

Comment: Have you been using Hylafax (of www.hylafax.org) or Hylafax+ (of hylafax.sourceforge.net) ??

Comment: hylafax.org, i've never come across hylafax+